# Find null space of wide matrix with repeated columns and a $0$ row

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

The null space of
$$ R = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&x&x&x&0&x&\\
0&1&x&x&x&0&x&\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&x&\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

is equal to the span of these four column vectors (written transposed)

\begin{bmatrix} x&x&1&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x&x&0&1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x&x&0&0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x&x&x&0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}

Is this correct? I just read off which combinations make sense off the matrix.

Comment: Your answer is close. How did you arrive there? You can check if a vector v is in the null space by seeing if Rv=0.

Comment: Yes that's pretty much what I did, I just looked at the combinations of the columns and read off which coefficients will always result in vectors v such that $Rv=0$. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 linearly independent columns: 1st, 2nd, 6th. Which means your Null Space should contain $7-3=4$ vectors. You need to express dependent columns via independent ones. But in your answer the last (7th) column isn't expressed by the Null Space - which is a hint that you did something wrong.

As mentioned in the comments - your vectors ($v$) in Null Space should $Rv=0$. But your answer gives e.g.:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&x&x&x&0&x&\\
0&1&x&x&x&0&x&\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&x&\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x\\x\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} x + x\\x+x\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$

To get $0$ you need to subtract vectors, not add them:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&x&x&x&0&x&\\
0&1&x&x&x&0&x&\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&x&\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x\\x\\-1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
You need to do similar thing with all 4 vectors in Null Space. E.g. the last one would be:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x\\x\\0\\0\\0\\x\\-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
I think you can take it from here and figure out the other 2.

Comment: oh ok  so just make the 1 negative in all four of my vectors

Comment: @ZackHelms, yep, and change the last vector too, it's not just about sign there.